# PHP and MySQL - Inserting values into table using identifier

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to insert values into a table using PHP.

This is the code for form

```
...<table>...
<?php
    $query2=("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id=$id");
    $result2=mysql_query($query2);
    while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row2[3]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row2[4]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row2[5]; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
---
<form name="reply" method="post" action="reply.php?id=<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>">
    <textarea name="reply" placeholder="Reply"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
---
```

As you can see, I'm using a query to figure out id value and try forcing that value into form action.

And this is the code to submit form

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connect.php");

$nametemp=$_SESSION['name'];
$hour=date('H:i');
$idtemp=$_GET['id'];
$reply=($_POST['reply']);

mysql_query("INSERT into testtab2 (id, nama, content, time) VALUES ('$idtemp', '$nametemp', '$reply', '$hour')");
header("location:discussion.php"); die();
?>
```

The code works well, but the id (not primary key) value when inserted into table is always 0 instead of whatever the real id is, the other values inserted properly. What am I doing wrong? Help is appreciated.

Comment: Avoid `mysql`, try to use `mysqli` or `pdo`.

Comment: I would have wrote some of my code again, I don't have much time. So, I  can't.

Comment: It's all up to you, but in the long run it'll become a problem.

Comment: What is the point of the `while`?  It looks like you only have one row.

Comment: try either $row[0] $row[1] or $row[2], figure out at what position in the array the id is stored.

Comment: Your second script (which handles the submissions) is subject to SQL injection attacks because you use `$_POST` and `$_GET` in the query. Never use user input directly in queries.

Comment: have you tried to echo the insert SQL and see what it is look like? Then you try to run that SQL on your database directly to check it is work or not. And also echo the id to check the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for posting. After many hours of trial and errors, I have successfully inserted the id into my table by using $_SESSION['idtemp'] first then declaring said session into variable $idtemp.

```
$idtemp=$_SESSION['idtemp'];
```